# Terraform - passing a template to a module

Tags: terraform

I want to pass a string value to a module in terraform, and have the module render it based on the variables defined in the module.  Something like

```
module "test" {
  source = "./test"
  template = "This is a templated string ${var.user}"
  user = "Bob"
}
```

But I don't want the template string evaluated until it's inside the module.  Is there an easy way to either prevent template rendering, or force template rendering again once inside the module?

Things I've considered thus far:

- the `templatefile` function.  The string isn't coming from a file, and isn't really designed to come from a file.
- The `format` or `replace` functions.  While they will probably work, it feels like a square peg round hole solution, where I'm forcing things.

Comment: I kind of feel that without a real life example it's hard to comprehend what the idea is. What do you mean with "But I don't want the template string evaluated until it's inside the module."? What does evalution mean in this cotext? Variable substition? Also, the `templatefile` function is not an option because the string is not in a file? Or you don't want it written to a file?

Comment: The Terraform language does not include have any way to separate template definition from template evaluation, so I have the same feedback as Marko E: I'd suggest editing your question to be able the underlying problem you are trying to solve, rather than a particular solution you're considering, so that readers can potentially propose other ways to address that problem. (See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for more on why.)